# Allowing the User to input a name for my table in SQL

Tags: php, sql, forms

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Php form for MySQL</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="home.php" method="post">
<p>
    <label for="table">Name your Table</label>
    <input type="text" name="table" id="table">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstName">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastName">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="emailAddress">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="emailAddress">
</p>
<button name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Create Table</button>
</form>
```

```
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

  //enter database details
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$table = $_POST['table'];

// Create a MySQL table in the selected database
mysqli_query("CREATE TABLE $table (
firstname VARCHAR(30), 
lastname VARCHAR(30),
email VARCHAR(50))") or die(mysql_error());  

 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table account created successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
 }

  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
     echo "Connected successfully";

  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  if(isset($_POST['firstname']) || ($_POST['lastname']) || ($_POST['email']))
{   
  $order="INSERT INTO $table (firstname,lastname,email) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email')";
$result = mysqli_query($order) or die (mysql_error());
}


  mysqli_close($conn);
  }

 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm trying to allow the user to pick a name for the database and was stuck. I get an error

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

**Picture of what I want:**

[image: Here is a picture of what I want]

I don't know what to do. Hope you can help. Thanks

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli_` and `mysql_` for one thing; *why?*

Comment: I dont know? which one should I use and how?

Comment: Use `mysqli_*`, `mysql_*` has been deprecated since PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7

Comment: Can you show me to what I change it to? by inputting it below? Thanks

Comment: You need to use the API from connection to querying. I'd opt more for `mysqli_` if you're going to use `mysqli_` or PDO. But again, you can't mix `mysqli_` with PDO.

Comment: and these will fail you btw, `|| ($_POST['lastname']) || ($_POST['email'])`. You have too many syntax errors. Have you not read any tutorials?

Comment: Why are you allowing your user add a table? It seems like you should be using an `insert` query instead of a `create table` query.  In 10 years, I've never run into a situation where I've had to allow a user to make a table.  Create one table with `firstname,lastname,email` and just `insert` new records as needed.

Comment: I did some of it what else do I need to do?

Comment: If I were you, I'd google 'SQL Injection'. Anyone who writes SQL queries should know what it is, why it's bad, and how to prevent it.  Mostly, using PDO or mysqli will make it easy to prevent, but you still need to be aware of it.

Comment: Ok but can you tell me what I need to change in my code?

Comment: @Tomi Not to be cruel, but the answer to that is "pretty much everything". You need to do some basic and *modern* PHP+MySQL tutorials (perhaps with a framework like Laravel to start) and you need to look into SQL injection and how it works. Right now, this code is highly dangerous and could be used to compromise your database.

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting means you're not providing valid credentials to connect to the database.  Don't update them in your question, because these details should be private, but you need to change the code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";
```

to be the actual values.  For instance, if your mysql username is `'tomi'`, the username line would look like this:
`$username = "tomi";`

You don't really have a database named 'database' do you?  And if your actual password is 'password' you need to change it to something more secure.

Answer (score 0):

You open a `mysqli` connection, and then use `mysql_query` to make a query, when it should be `mysqli_query`. `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` are very different things, and you should never use `mysql_*` anymore. After changing this, check your authentication details. As long as you're on a private machine, maybe use `var_dump()` to look at them and make sure they're what you expect them to be. It looks like they might be getting passed into `mysqli` as empty strings. If your auth details are absolutely correct, double check that the given user in the database actually has the required privileges.

Comment: Can you show me to what I change it to? by inputting it below? Thanks

Comment: @Tomi Let's just try one thing at a time. Replace your `mysql_query` statements with `mysqli_query`, and your `mysql_error` with `mysqli_error($conn)`

Comment: And as Fred says, you need `isset()` around all of your `$_POST` checks, not just the first one.

Comment: I am very new to php so dont really know what I'm doing. Could you write the connections underneath? Thank you

Comment: I did some of it what else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Editing my top answer with the full php code that I think will work for you:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

  //enter database details
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";
  $dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    echo "Failed to connect: (" . $conn->connect_error . ") ";
}
$table = $_POST['table'];

// SQL to Create a table in the selected database
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30), 
lastname VARCHAR(30),
email VARCHAR(50))";  


 if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Table account created successfully";
  } else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . $conn->error;
 }

  // Check connection
  if (!$conn) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
     echo "Connected successfully";

  $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

if(isset($_POST['firstname']) || isset($_POST['lastname']) || isset($_POST['email'])) {   
    $order="INSERT INTO $table (firstname,lastname,email) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email')";

    if ($conn->query($order) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $order . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

}


  $conn->close();
  }

 ?>
```

IMPORTANT:

1) 
 Make sure you enter the correct database details at the top of the php code. For example for me with xampp on windows it is:

```
  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "database";
```

where I have previously created the database "database" manualy.

2)  If you want to make sure in your later part of the code that all fields are NOT empty, you might prefer to use && (and) instead of || (or) for your conditions in the if. Currently it will run even as long as ANY of the fields are filled in, even if the rest of the fields are EMPTY.

Example:

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['lastname']) && isset($_POST['email'])) {
```

instead of:

```
if(isset($_POST['firstname']) || isset($_POST['lastname']) || isset($_POST['email'])) {
```

I also highly suggest you check out the different ways to implement MySQLi with php; for example
Creating tables: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_create_table.asp

Comment: Sorry my mistake changes that. What else do I need to do? Thanks

Comment: I have just eddited my top comment with a full "home.php" that should work for you